# How to create Postgres regression test database

Tags: postgresql

The [Postgres documentation for the EXPLAIN command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) states that

> Examples in this section are drawn from the regression test database after doing a VACUUM ANALYZE, using 9.3 development sources. You should be able to get similar results if you try the examples yourself (...)

How do I set up the regression test database?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/regress-run.html Easily found on google: "postgresql regression test database"

Comment: @JorgeCampos I found that page too. It's about running the test suite. It doesn't explain how to set up the DB. It's not even clear that it uses the same schema as what the EXPLAIN docs reference.

Comment: Well from there all you need to do is to download the source code. Where you will find the regression database code. To make it easier: Another google serch: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/src/test/regress

Comment: @Stephen: The database is created as part of the test suite. Follow the "[Existing Installation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/regress-run.html#AEN38775)" steps, and it should leave behind a DB called `regression`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/regress-run.html#AEN44834).

You `./configure` and `make install` the PostgreSQL software, then create a database cluster with `initdb`.

Then you set `PGPORT` and `PGUSER` (if you want something nonstandard) and run

```
make installcheck
```

for the regular test suite or

```
make installcheck-world
```

for the extended test suite.

After that, you'll have a new database called `regression` with all kinds of objects created by the tests, which can be useful for testing.

Comment: I had an existing installation with [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/). I installed postgres from source separately, but then I was able to run `make installcheck` against my Postgres.app server and end up with the `regression` DB there. However it appears that installing from source is still required to provide dependencies for `make installcheck`.

Comment: Right. The regression tests are intended for PostgreSQL hackers or packagers.

Comment: Update: Postgres.app does include a bin directory, so it's possible to get the regression DB installed with `./configure --bindir /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin`, then `make installcheck`.